# Json Schema validate reference property on same object

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Using JSON Schema 7 to perform validations

Is the below validation possible using json schema.

```
 {
    properties : [{name: "a"}, {name: "b"}, {name: "c"}],
    rules : [{ prop : ["a","b"] }, { prop : ["a"] }, {prop: ["c"]}]
 }
```

The "prop" property in object is dependent values in properties.

ie only of "properties.name" exists then that value can be added to the "prop" array

Note:

- The "properties" array can have any object of type {name : }
- "name" can have any possible string, which i don't know beforehand

I have been going through documentation, but can find a answer.

Is this validation not supported in Json Schema yet?

Comment: This is not something you can do in JSON Schema, and it is not something we will be adding. This is more business logic. JSON Schema focuses on the shame and structure of your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with a static JSON schema.

To archive it you would need a dynamic schema validation, but this could be dangerous to code injection from malicious users:

```
const Ajv = require('ajv')

const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true, jsonPointers: true })

const data = {
  properties: [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' }],
  rules: [{ prop: ['a', 'b'] }, { prop: ['a', 'zz'] }, { prop: ['c'] }]
}

const validProp = data.properties.map(_ => _.name)

const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  required: ['properties', 'rules'],
  properties: {
    properties: {
      type: 'array',
      items: {
        type: 'object',
        required: ['name'],
        properties: {
          name: { type: 'string' }
        }
      }
    },
    rules: {
      type: 'array',
      items: {
        type: 'object',
        required: ['prop'],
        properties: {
          prop: {
            type: 'array',
            uniqueItems: true,
            items: {
              type: 'string',
              enum: validProp // here happen the validation
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const isValid = ajv.validate(schema, data)
if (!isValid) {
  console.log(ajv.errors)
}
```